# Database stored image in Listview on android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have to implement a searched list view with images.. I implemented searching method and listing the details.. How i can put the images in listview on corner..

- The images will be in sqlite database... How i can get the image from database? How i can put that into a array adapter? Right now only one string include

Code is:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> results1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

[here](https://plus.google.com/photos/111266316610051914435/albums/5813219256697437521?banner=pwa&authkey=CKDDiaS8g_Spfg) the result in string will be in adapter.. how i can declare the image with these adapater... [1](https://plus.google.com/photos/111266316610051914435/albums/5813219256697437521?banner=pwa&authkey=CKDDiaS8g_Spfg):

Comment: So what have you tried and what hasn't worked for you?

Comment: use a blob to store the image, or store a plain file and put the file path as a string in the db. if you use a database, use a cursor adapter rather than an array adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the images using blob (byte[]) into sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

you can store image by convert into base64 string..by following way.

this is the function to decode the base64 String to Image(Bitmap)...

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
    {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
    }
```

and this is the function to encode the image to base64 String

```
 public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    return imageEncoded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this answer reads the image from the database, change accordingly to your requirement:

```
 SQLiteDatabase myDb;       
           String MySQL;
           byte[] byteImage1 = null; 
           byte[] byteImage2 = null;
           MySQL="create table emp1(_id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, sample TEXT not null, picture BLOB);";
           myDb = openOrCreateDatabase("Blob List", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
           myDb.execSQL(MySQL);
           String s=myDb.getPath();
           textView.append("\r\n" + s+"\r\n");       
           myDb.execSQL("delete from emp1");
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
           newValues.put("sample", "HI Hello");


        try
        {
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/Pictures/picture.jpg"); 
        BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream); 
        byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()]; 
        bif.read(byteImage1); 
        textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage1.length+"\r\n"); 
        newValues.put("picture", byteImage1); 

        long ret = myDb.insert("emp1", null, newValues); 
        if(ret<0) textView.append("\r\n!!! Error add blob filed!!!\r\n");
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            textView.append("\r\n!!! Error: " + e+"!!!\r\n");   
        }


        Cursor cur = myDb.query("emp1",null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            textView.append("\r\n" + cur.getString(1)+"\r\n");
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    ///////Read data from blob field////////////////////
        cur.moveToFirst();
        byteImage2=cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("picture")); 
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0, byteImage2.length));
        textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage2.length+"\r\n"); 

        cur.close();

        myDb.close();
```